# Error:The specified cast from a materialized 'System.TimeSpan' type to the 'System.DateTime' type is not valid

Tags: entity-framework

I am doing my application in MVC. I am using stored procedure to list some 
values. I calling that procedure in my controller.

My Procedure is

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGetWaitingList]
@BusinessUserId int 
As 
Begin
SELECT WorkHour.WorkHourId, WorkHour.EndTime, WorkHour.Description, tblApp.EndDate
FROM WorkHour INNER JOIN
    tblApp ON WorkHour.BusinessUserId = tblApp.UserId2 and WorkHour.EndTime < Cast (tblApp.EndDate as Time)
End
```

My controllercode is

```
var parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
parameters[0] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "BusinessUserId", Value = id };
List<Appt> wt = new List<Appt>();
using (SYTEntities context = new SYTEntities())
{
  wt = context.Database.SqlQuery<Appt>("exec spGetWaitingList @BusinessUserId", parameters).ToList(); 
}
```

My model Appt is

```
public class Appt
{
    public int BusinessID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string BusinessCategory { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeID { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
    public string AddCustomer { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime HolidayDate { get; set; } 
    public string HolidayDesc { get; set; }
}
```

In Database I specified the end time as datatype TIME

While running the application am getting an error like this
[image: Erro]

Can anyone please help me to solve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show you model for `Appt`. And what is the database data type for `EndTime`

Comment: `StartTime` and `EndTime` in your model should be `DateTime`, not `TimeSpan`. If you want to use TimeSpan, I guess `DateTimeOffset` should be used for the coresponding columns on the server side instead of `Time`.